# Rails / RSpec: speccing model behaviour that has a dependency on another model?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, bdd

I'm working on a Rails application that tracks customer details (stored as a `Customer`, naturally) and enables users to generate snapshot batches (`Batch`) of a set of customer records, based on a set of pre-defined criteria.

The `Batch` model is responsible for collating records for a CSV, as well as updating a status field of each record.

I'm struggling to get my head around how to best spec the batch generation routines using RSpec, namely – stubbing the Customer dependency.

Should I be creating a pre-determined set of Customer records that I can use to ensure my rules are correct (ie, given records a through k, this batch should not include records b, d or f), or should I be attempting to mock/stub them out somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Decisions like this are always contextual, but, generally speaking, I recommend using real models and the database when specifying behavior of finders.